# Upload local wordpress site to live free wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, mamp

I am using wordpress for the first time, I have created a news/blog website called trimline news. I have created the site locally using MAMP, (modifying the twenty eleven theme). 
What I want to is upload the website I have made to a free wordpress site, so trimlinenews.wordpress.com, I have been looking for tutorials online how to do this but I can only find ones that require you to have your own server and domain.

Can anyone please help me out, or point me in the direction for help with this.

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the the hosted blog into a XML file and import it into wordpress.com site
See below link in wordpress support

[Moving a blog](http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/)

Wordpress.com does not provide [FTP access](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/migrating-existing-site-to-wordpresscom) so it's not possible to upload your theme. You can just import the content on your blog. You need to select a similar theme in the wordpress dashboard and purchase a [Custom Design upgrade](http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/#editing-themes) for editing your theme.

Comment: thanks ill give this a shot, will this sort out the phpmyadmin database also?

Comment: ok, so i managed to upload it, all the categories, posts etc have been uploaded, but the theme i created has not been uploaded. I modified the twenty eleven theme when creating on local

Comment: so I cannot edit a theme if I am using wordpress for free? the edit link under Appearance > Edit is no longer there

Answer (score 0):

Export your content locally - Dashboard>>Tools>>Export - and import it at wordpress.com

You can't upload a complete theme folder to .COM ; no FTP access. You will need to redo your edits in a copy of the theme at .COM with the custom CSS upgrade.

See [The difference between WordPress.com, WordPress, and WordPress.org](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)